# Grails 3.0.6 java.lang.IllegalStateException on any integration test

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing, spock

```
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import spock.lang.Specification

@Integration
class MySpec extends Specification {

   def setup() {
   }

   def cleanup() {
   }

    void "test something"() {
        expect:"tests a"
          true
    }
}

MySpec > test something FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

1 test completed, 1 failed
:integrationTest FAILED
:mergeTestReports

I run 
"test-app -integration MySpec" command

Is that an error in grails or I do smth wrong?

UPDATE!

**I found a solution - just add 
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
to build.gradle**

Comment: I saw a similar classnotfound error and for me it was solved by adding `testCompile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.26'` to `build.gradle`

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Testing was never so easy and intuitive before the use of Spock.We can always test the exceptions in grails Spock Testing. For example we have a method which throws exception like :

```
String getUserType(int age){
    if(age<=0){
        throw new MyException("Invalid age")
    }else if( age>0 && age<50){
        return "Young"
    }else{
        return "Old"
    }
}
```

Now we will write the test case of this method for checking whether exception is thrown for invalid inputs or not.

```
def "exception should be thrown only for age less than or equal to 0"{
    given:
        String type = getUserType(34)
    expect:
        type == "Young"
        notThrown MyException
    when:
        type = getUserType(0)
    then:
        thrown MyException
}
```

This is how we have tested whether exception is thrown for invalid input or not.
Hope it helps

Comment: How your answer is related to the question? It was about exception but not Spock.